# $A,B$ are square matrices. Is it true that if $A+B^{-1} = I$ and $A^2 = 0$, then $AB = BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As titled, $A,B$ are square matrices, I tried to determine if $A+B^{-1} = I$ and $A^2 = 0$, then $AB = BA$.

Edit:
I tried:
$$A+B^{-1} = I \Rightarrow A=I-B^{-1}$$
Hence,
$$ A^2 = (I-B^{-1})(I-B^{-1}) = I-B^{-1}-B^{-1}+ (B^{-1})^2 = 0 $$
$$\Rightarrow (B^{-1})^2 = 2B^{-1} - I$$
Right- or left-multiplying $B$ gives
$$ B^{-1} = 2I - B \Rightarrow B = 2I - B^{-1} $$
Thus,
$$ AB = A \cdot (2I - B^{-1}) = 2A - AB^{-1} $$
$$ BA = (2I - B^{-1}) \cdot A =2A - B^{-1}A $$
Not sure how to proceed.

As suggested in the comment:
Since $A+B^{-1} = I$,

$$B = (A+B^{-1}) \cdot B = AB +I$$
$$B = B \cdot (A+B^{-1}) = BA + I $$
Hence, $$AB = BA$$
It makes sense to me, but I am wondering if we need to use $A^2 = 0$.

Comment: Surely if you pre and post multiply $A + B^{-1} = I$ by $B$ you will get $AB + I = B$ and $BA+I=B$ from which it follows that $AB=BA$?

Comment: Isn't $A^2=0$, so in second line of your work, how is $A^2=I$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It is a horrible mistake that I made.

Answer (score 2):

From $A + B^{-1} = 1$, one gets $B^{-1} = 1 - A$. Now,
since
$$(1-A)(1+A) = 1-A^2 = 1-0 = 1$$
it follows that $B = 1 + A$. Therefore
$$
AB = A(1+A) = A + A^2 = A = A^2 + A = (A+1)A = BA
$$